# Guzzle error 500

Tags: php, laravel-5, guzzle

so i have a CURL request that looks like this (and it works):

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Token 1234567890" http://api.website.com
```

tried translating it into Laravel Guzzle into something like this:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://api.website.com']);
$headers = ['Authorization' => 'Token 1234567890'];
$response = $client->get($query_string, $headers);
return $response;
```

but i'm getting a 500 error. i think there's something wrong in how i implemented the headers. sorry, very new in laravel and guzzle.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get()` takes `options` (which can contain headers) as a second parameter, not headers ([docs](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html#headers)).

This should work:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://api.website.com']);
$headers = ['Authorization' => 'Token 1234567890'];
$response = $client->get(
    $query_string, [
        "headers" => $headers
        // you can add more options here
    ]
);
return $response;
```

Comment: Sorry, tried that and it's still returning a 500 error :/ maybe the `Authorization` part is translated into a different word when used by cURL PHP or Guzzle

Comment: oh! i think there's something wrong with my post request, but when i hardcoded the URL passed, it returned the json data that i was looking for! man that was stupid not knowing the exact error haha. thanks!